# Spotipy popularity value is different than the value retrieved from Spotify API

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I was trying to get data on spotify tracks in a playlist, and while I was running over the playlist with a script I noticed that some of the values seem odd - for example, one of the songs that I went over, "Somebody Told Me" by The Killers, got a popularity score of 0. When I cross checked on the Spotify Developer console, it said that the popularity score is 75. I also tried this on a few other low scored tracks and their popularity value was also incorrect.

I checked some of the other "normal looking" values and they were correct, so it seems that it only happens for some of the tracks.

Any help/explanation would be appreciated!

Edit: Here's the script in question

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

# Set up API credentials
client_id = 'CLIENT-ID-HERE'
client_secret = 'CLIENT-SECRET-HERE'
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

# Define playlist ID
playlist_id = 'PLAYLIST-ID-HERE'

# Get tracks in the playlist
results = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id)
tracks = results['items']
while results['next']:
    results = sp.next(results)
    tracks.extend(results['items'])

counter = 0

for track in tracks:
    # Get track details
    track_info = sp.track(track['track']['id'])
    track_name = track_info['name']
    track_artists = [artist['name'] for artist in track_info['artists']]
    track_release_date = track_info['album']['release_date']

    # Get audio features
    audio_features = sp.audio_features(track['track']['id'])[0]
    try:
        track_genre = sp.artist(track_info['artists'][0]['id'])['genres'][0]
    except: 
        print(f"Track name: {track_name}")
        print("----------------------------")
        continue 
    track_bpm = audio_features['tempo']
    track_energy = audio_features['energy']
    track_danceability = audio_features['danceability']
    track_loudness = audio_features['loudness']
    track_valence = audio_features['valence']
    track_length = audio_features['duration_ms'] / 1000
    track_acousticness = audio_features['acousticness']
    track_speechiness = audio_features['speechiness']
    track_popularity = track_info['popularity']

    # Print track information
    print(f"Track name: {track_name}")
    print(f"Artists: {', '.join(track_artists)}")
    print(f"Genre: {track_genre}")
    print(f"Release date: {track_release_date}")
    print(f"BPM: {track_bpm}")
    print(f"Energy: {track_energy}")
    print(f"Danceability: {track_danceability}")
    print(f"Loudness: {track_loudness}")
    print(f"Valence: {track_valence}")
    print(f"Length: {track_length}")
    print(f"Acousticness: {track_acousticness}")
    print(f"Speechiness: {track_speechiness}")
    print(f"Popularity: {track_popularity}")
    print("----------------------------")
    counter+=1
```

Another thing I noticed; I made a new playlist with some of the problematic songs and the popularity was accurate. I tried adding more songs, and when I passed the 10 song mark some songs after it had the wrong popularity.

Comment: This is strange, can you share the code of your script?

Comment: @rob_med I added the script to my post along with another piece of information

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and did a bit of diagnosing.

Issue appears to be associated with the using the default None for the market variable, updating your call to:

`results = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id, market='US')`

Where 'US' is an example for the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code you want to find the popularity of the song for should fix it.

When I was using the default market=None it was returning 0 popularity scores. I am no expert but I would guess that maybe it zeroes out if the song isn't available in a certain country.